# Benefits of using NServicebus or Masstransit with TIBCO EMS

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit, tibco-ems

We are exploring the design to incorporate TIBCO EMS into our .NET based system. From what I read, broth NServiceBus and MassTransit can use TIBCO EMS as the transportation communication layer. My question is: what are the benefit of using NServiceBus or MassTransit over using custom C#/.NET library over TIBCO EMS directly?

I am aware of this answer about RabbitMQ: [What does MassTransit add to RabbitMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296787/what-does-masstransit-add-to-rabbitmq?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Are the same benefits applied to TIBCO EMS too?

Comment: If you are still investigating service bus options you may want to take a look at Shuttle (http://shuttle.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits would be similar to those over any other transport (like RabbitMQ). While TIBCO can do more than a lot of messaging systems, it also depends on how much you want to do inside it vs. in your application using TIBCO.

Where I work, we interact with TIBCO regularly but a different team manages that and we just consume services. We do use MassTransit with RabbitMQ and MSMQ (yes, both).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pros and cons of doing inside TIBCO vs. in the app through MassTransit/NServicebus?

Comment: And, can you share your experiences/reasoning of using RabbitMQ/MSMQ over TIBCO? Thank you.

Comment: When we started on the project, the TIBCO project wasn't ready for consumption and we were only connecting concerns in our group. It wasn't needed to reach outside our group to talk to other parts of our application. Additionally, components of TIBCO likely need to be written in Java, and my team is primarily .NET.